# os.listdir() returns nothing, not even an empty list

Tags: python

During a presentation yesterday I had a colleague run one of my scripts on a fresh installation of Python 3.8.1. It was able to create and write to a csv file in his folder (proof that the csv library was working correctly), but everything else failed due to not being able to find the needed files. To try and isolate the problem and figure out why, we tried the below simple script, which also failed.

He had this test.py script in "D:/TEST", which also contained some folders and image files. Running this script printed nothing to the console. No empty list, no error message, no newline. Maybe the print() function was also not working, but I didn't get around to testing that.

```
import os

print(os.listdir())
```

This script works fine on my computer and my other colleagues computers (all Windows 10, similar hardware). I didn't have time to look into the issue more thoroughly and don't have access to his computer anymore. What could be the problem? What other things could I have him look into in order to fix this? In case this problem appears again during a future presentation, what steps could I take to figure out the cause of it?

Comment: was it literally just those two lines in a fresh python runtime?

Comment: If you had the errant machine, I would insert the line `print('xyzzy')` as the first line. It *may* be that the script is not even running (if, for example, you had an empty  `python.cmd` file - yes, unlikely, but certainly possible).

Comment: How did you run the script?  Double clicking or via command line?  And if via command line, did you specify the Python command + script (`python test.py`), or just the script?  There is a chance that Python never saw your script, and it was interpreted by something else.

Comment: In theory there could be a site configuration file that's rebinding `print` (e.g. `def print(*args): pass`) or causing the interpreter to exit before even getting to the script. Try [`python -S`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#id3) to bypass the site config.

Comment: @Natthaphon An error would produce an error message. And besides, the `path` parameter for [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) has been optional since actually 3.2, which is very old.

Comment: My bad, I check it in official site but you don't need that in 3.8.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh yes, just those two lines.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thank you. I would like to try that. However, the original script with the csv writer was running, so I think this script would have been running as well?

Comment: @caxcaxcoatl It was run by entering "python test.py" into the terminal in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @wjandrea I did not know about that option. I will have him try that. Thank you.

Comment: @wjandrea He tried creating a new python file containing just print("Hello World!") and tried running it by entering "python -S test.py". Nothing was printed to the console. Maybe it is a corrupted Python installation, so he is going to try reinstalling Python.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague uninstalled Python and reinstalled it. After doing this apparently the "python" command will no longer run his scripts, but using "py" instead will. Now that he is using "py" to run his scripts, it is working as expected.